# How to monitor liabilities in the plaid

Tags: plaid

I am using Liabilities in my system, but I need to monitor the debt from time to time. Is it possible to do this monitoring without the user having to log into Plaid again? If so, which endpoint do I need to use?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "monitoring the debt from time to time"? What information do you need and how often do you need it to be refreshed?

Comment: I need to make a graph of the debt and its amortizations as a function of time

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `/liabilities/get` endpoint to do this. The user only needs to log in to Plaid once, unless something happens to break their Plaid connection.

Comment: Yes, I am having problems updating /liabilities/get after the user logs in, because the endpoint needs the "public_token" that is generated through react-plaid-link. I need to monitor the liabilities without the user having to login again. Is this possible?

Comment: /liabilities/get does not take the public_token as a parameter -- if you are seeing that it does somewhere, can you copy and paste that text here? It takes an access_token, which is returned by /item/public_token/exchange

Comment: Currently in my system for the get/liabilities, I use the return from itemPublicTokenExchange, and pass as parameter the access_token. My question is: To generate the access_token I need the public_token that comes from the react-plaid link, how can I get the passives without the user logging in again?

Comment: I need to create a CronJob, to monitor these liabilities without the need for the user to log on again.

Comment: You can just re-use the existing access_token -- you don't need to generate a new one every time you call /liabilities/get.